# What is the most efficient way to create multiple subplots with `statsmodels.api.qqplot()`?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, statsmodels

Currently this code block generates 8x1 subplots. I want the code block to generate 2x4 subplots in the most efficient way. Please help!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

# load the dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/wine.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None)
normal_stat = df.loc[:,:7]

# generate subplots
for i in range(len(normal_stat.columns)):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    ax=plt.subplot(2,4,1+i)
    sm.qqplot(df[normal_stat.columns[i]], line='s', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(str(normal_stat.columns[i]) + ' QQ Plot')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

To plot only the first 7 qq-plots:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=2, sharex=True, figsize=(4*3, 2*3))
for k, ax in zip(df.columns, np.ravel(axes)):
    if k >= 7:
        ax.set_visible(False)
    else:
        sm.qqplot(df[k], line='s', ax=ax)
        ax.set_title(f'{k} QQ Plot')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Note: we could have limited the `zip` iterator to the first 7 columns by saying `for k, ax in zip(df.columns[:7], np.ravel(axes))`, but it would leave the 8th subplot shown (as an empty box). The method above explicitly hides the plots that we don't want.

**Original answer**

You can do this:

```py
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=2, sharex=True, figsize=(4*3, 2*3))
for k, ax in zip(df.columns, np.ravel(axes)):
    sm.qqplot(df[k], line='s', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'{k} QQ Plot')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: resulting figure of 2x4 qq-plots]

**Explanation**

The `ncols=4, nrows=2` arguments mandate 8 subplots, arranged in two rows. But the resulting axes is a nested length-2 list of length-4 lists. So we use `np.ravel` to flatten that. Then we use `zip()` to iterate concurrently on the columns of `df` and these axes. The iterator will stop when the shortest of columns and axes iterator is reached, which in this case is the 8 axes (so we don't even have to explicitly slice the `df` columns).

Finally, the `plt.tight_layout()` is used to space the subplots in a way that the labels are more readable and the subplots more nicely separated.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful answer Pierre! Just want to tweak something here. I just want to display only 7 subplots and not have the 8th ax show. How can I do that? Thanks again!

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for your fast, efficient, and very well-explained answer!

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for providing a reproducible example and code in your first question on SO, well done! I had upvoted your question because of this. Not sure who downvoted or why.